# Derive the formula (n-m+1) number of comparisons for worst case Brute-force string matching algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I am trying to understand how `(n-m+1)` (`n` being the string and `m` being the pattern) is derived. As in, how could you determine a formula for the number of comparisons in the worst case of a brute-force string matching algorithm.

Here is a look at `(n-m+1)` being mathmatically derived (where I'm at), that I found:
[image]

In the above derivation, I am unable to see where the `+1` comes into the equation mathmatically.

Comment: Please show us where are you stuck. This is a pretty standard problem with tons of explanation all over the internet.

Comment: What is the number of substrings of length $m$ in a string of length $n$?

Comment: @RinkeshP I updated my question to better show what I mean! I want to see how it is mathmatically derived! I dont doubt that `(n-m+1)` is the number of comparisons, but I want to understand the WHY. Like you would explaining to someone the classic ""Why do you have to have the -1​ in `i <= array.length-1​` in the for loop?".

Comment: @greybeard THANK YOU FOR THAT! I ran with it, then found this question asked on the mathmatics Stack Exchange: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141044/number-of-substrings-of-length-m-in-a-string-of-length-n) and the answers was exactly what I was looking for (after I explained it my way to the imaginary 10 year-old in my brain, Feynman technique style haha)!

Comment: @RinkeshP & greybeard You both can still answer my question in your own words (now that you have a better asked version of my question in that link), if youd like! Who knows, it could further my understanding of it!